# PHPExcel and subtotal

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to parse XLSX files. I have found that SUBTOTAL() cells are not ignored when aggregating values with functions such as SUM(). Is there a setting or something that needs to be set to force PHPExcel to not take cells with the SUBTOTAL formula into account when summing over it? Maybe some workaround if this is not possible?

Comment: use subtotal() rather than sum() which should ignore the previous subtotals(). This is the outcome when doing it in natively in Excel or PHPExcel

Comment: It seems that PHPExcel does not ignore subtotal cells. When parsing a XLSX file, some cell values I get do not correspond with the values in the Excel file. The reason for this is the mentioned subtotal issue. I cannot change the format of the XLSX files that need to be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I wrote a function similar to the toArray() function to parse through the Excel sheet and return previously cached values (stored in the "v" tag in the sheet xml). This prevents PHPExcel from trying to calculate cell values. Such a function was not exposed by PHPExcel. Note that it uses the calculated value in the case where the cached value is not available. Practically speaking, the cached value should always be available as the sheet will be generated by Excel, which populates the cached value field.

```
function getCachedSheetData($sheet)
{
    /*  Usage
     sheet: $excel_obj->getActiveSheet()
    */

    // This function is similar to the toArray function, but returns previously cached values to prevent PHPExcel from calculating any formulas
    $toreturn = array();

    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
    {
        $toreturn[] = array();

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells, even if it is not set. By default, only cells that are set will be iterated.

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell)
        {
            if ($cell->getOldCalculatedValue() === null)
            {
                $toreturn[$cell->getRow()][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getValue();
            }
            else
            {
                $toreturn[$cell->getRow()][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getOldCalculatedValue();
            }
        }
    }

    return $toreturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If covering the full range of subtotals a simple workaround is to accept that all values will be SUMmed (as desired) and then also all the SUBTOTALs too - which should come to the same total anyway, so simply SUM and divide result by 2.

Comment: Unfortunately one cant assume that the subtotal cells will necessarily cover the whole range of cells that will be summed, so one cant simply divide the result by two